# Login_Required Django Not Working With FormView

Tags: python, django, authentication, decorator, formview

I have a FormView that is basically a product page. You can view product details and request the product from a form on that page. I want the page to be set up so that anyone can view the page, but only people that are logged in can request the product. To do this, I added a login_required decorator to the post function in the FormView, but I get the error:

> 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'user'

How can I code this view/form so it acts as I described?

View:

```
class RedeemReward(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'reward.html'
    slug_field = 'reward_slug'
    form_class = Redeem_Reward
    model = Reward

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(RedeemReward, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        #form = self.get_form(self.get_form_class())
        #form.save(self.request.POST)
        form.save(self.request.POST)
        return super(RedeemReward, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('reward_confirmation', args=(self.object.reward_slug, self.object.reward_code))

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super(RedeemReward, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Form:

```
class Redeem_Reward(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(label=_('Quantity'), error_messages={'invalid':'Must be a valid number'})
    reward_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.HiddenInput(), label=_('Reward Name'), error_messages={'invalid':'Invalid reward'})
    def clean_quantity(self):
        """
        Validate that the user entered a valid number.
        """
        return self.cleaned_data['quantity']
    def clean_reward_name(self):
        """
        Validate that this reward code exists.
        """
        try:
            existing_reward = Reward.objects.get(reward_name=self.cleaned_data['reward_name'])
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("The reward you requested does not exist."))
        return self.cleaned_data['reward_name']
    def save(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Save all of the required data.
        """
        user = request.user
        #user_points = Points.objects.filter(affiliate__id=user.id).annotate(total_points=Sum('points'))
        user_points = Affiliate.objects.filter(points__affiliate__id=user.id).annotate(total_points=Sum('points'))
        user_points = user_points[0].total_points
        error_message = {'lookuperror':'You need to provide a valid quantity', 
                         'insufficient_points':"You don't have enough points for this purchase."}
        try:
            quantity = self.cleaned_data['quantity']
            reward_name = self.cleaned_data['reward_name']
            rewards = Reward.objects.get(reward_name=reward_name)
        except LookupError:
            raise Http404
        try:
            points_cost = -(rewards.reward_cost * quantity)
        except ArithmeticError:
            raise Http404
        quote_price = -(points_cost)
        if user_points >= quote_price:
            reward_order = Points.objects.create(affiliate=user, reward=rewards, points=points_cost, from_reward=True, from_offer=False, from_referral=False)
            status_cost = Status_Code.objects.create(short_name="Pending", name="The order is currently being reviewed", description="The order is in queue")
            redeem_order = Redeem.objects.create(affiliate=user, reward=rewards, status_code=status_code)
            redeem_details = Redeem_Details.objects.create(redeem=redeem_order, quantity=quantity, quote_price=quote_price)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('reward_confirmation', args=(redeem_details.redeem_code,)))
        else:
            return render(request, 'reward.html', {'error_message':error_message['insufficient_points']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `self.request.POST` to your form's `save` method, which is set to expect a request as its first argument. Or at least something that has a `user` attribute. If you pass in `self.request` instead, you will no longer get that particular error.

It is odd that you're reinstantiating `form` in your `form_valid` method, which receives the bound form as an argument.

You're returning `HttpResponse` objects from your form's custom save method, which is nonstandard. But as long as you're doing that, you should return them from your `form_valid` method.

In summary, something like this:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    return form.save(self.request)
```

Comment: Thanks! However, when I deploy the project and complete the form, the new objects aren't created in the form save method. Do you know why?

Comment: Not by eyeballing it. I do see that you're returning an `HttpResponse` from your form's `save` method, which is not at all standard. Are you getting form errors if you thread that through?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, but when I login to the admin area, no new model objects were created

Comment: I've edited my answer based on seeing that you're using `FormView` rather than `ModelFormView`. There are only a couple of code paths your `save` can take - it either 404s, renders an error page, or creates the new objects and redirects to a confirmation page. Which path is happening?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used  your example and tweaked a couple of things and everything is pretty much fine now. I plan on redirecting to a confirmation page.